# Threads and resource sharing

Tags: c, multithreading, posix, mutex, semaphore

I have a school assignment that I need to accomplish. To provide a concise overview, I have extracted the essential details:

---

The objective of this assignment is to gain an understanding of multi-threaded programming by creating a dynamic number of threads and appropriately distributing tasks among them. Additionally, you are required to coordinate the progress of threads using checkpointing and locks. The task must be implemented using the C programming language and the POSIX thread library.

Your program will receive **a path to a metadata file** and the **maximum number of threads** that can be utilized as arguments in the console. The metadata file contains information about various input files and corresponding numbers needed for calculations.

Below is an example of the metadata file's format:

```
./input_files/file_1.txt
0.5
1

./input_files/file_2.txt
0.5
0.5
```

Your task is to read the metadata file and create an array consisting of **structures named "InputFile."** Each structure represents the information associated with a **single input file**.

How each struct will look:

```
typedef struct InputFile {

    char file_path[1024];
    
    float number_1;
    float number_2;

} InputFile;
```

Here is what each input file will contain (numbers will change for each file):

```
23
4
10
```

You are required to use this array of structures in conjunction with threads. For each file, you will open it and perform the necessary calculations. However, upon completing the processing of each file, you must combine the output of all files into a final result and print it to the console.

```
File_1
10
20
30

File_2
50
70
90

The output should be like this:
60  >> (50 + 10)
90  >> (70 + 20)
120 >> (30 + 90)
```

Keep in mind that there may be 5 files but only 2 threads, or vice versa, with 5 threads and 2 files. Your task is to devise a strategy to distribute these operations among the threads to ensure the program produces the correct result.

---

I have successfully obtained the metadata file and the number of threads. Furthermore, I have created an array named "InputFile_array" to store the input files as structs of "InputFile." Each element within this array corresponds to a struct that encapsulates all the information required to handle a specific file and perform the necessary operations on it.

I find the problem challenging in terms of determining an appropriate approach. If I were able to create as many threads as there are files, the solution would be straightforward. I could iterate through the array of structures using a for loop, associating each struct with a thread. Each thread would work independently on its assigned file, and I would wait for all threads to finish.

Unfortunately, this is not the situation here. Given that I can use mutex locks and semaphores, how can I approach this problem effectively?

Here is what I had in mind regarding "As many threads as files":

```
// I store the number of threads as "num_threads".
// I get the number of threads from the command line as an argument to my program.

InputFile InputFiles[num_threads]; // I use "num_threads" as the size because I assumed that the number of files and threads is the same.

// ...
// InputFiles gets populated by my program to contain information for each file.
// ...

pthread_t threads[num_threads];

// Create each thread and pass it the struct to start working. (1 struct or file per 1 thread)
for (size_t index = 0; index < num_threads; index++)
{
    if (pthread_create(&threads[index], NULL, &thread_function, InputFiles[index]) != 0)   // Each InputFile struct contains everything that the thread_function needs to get the job done.
    {
        perror("Failed to create thread");
        
        exit(1);    // I want the program to stop if something goes wrong.    
    }
}

// Now just wait for all threads to finish their work.
for (size_t index = 0; index < num_threads; index++)
{
    if (pthread_join(threads[index], NULL) != 0)
    {
        exit(2);
    }
    
    printf("Entire process has finished.\n");
}
```

Comment: _"as many threads as there are files"_ would be a rather ineffective method if there are many files. You can communicate with the threads using mutexes and condition variables. You could create a queue where you store the data for the threads to work with and then the threads can pick tasks from that queue until the queue is depleated, then the threads can all exit.

Comment: Can you post what you have tried?  And don't worry about how many threads or files you need to read.  If you get docked because you didn't use all threads, your teacher is, quite frankly, not qualified to be teaching advanced coding concepts.  Since you are specifically told the input values for threads and files are unknown, you **cannot** create an optimal distribution algorithm, even if that were desirable (it's usually more trouble than it's worth - a ***lot*** more trouble...).  Do as @TedLyngmo suggested - use a simple queue and have the threads just pull work from the queue.

Comment: Meta comment: it's a wall of text with snippets of code, you will be more successful here if you write a concise question with a [mre] (i.e. a program).  This skill will help you greatly in life especially in engineering.  Try to solving your problem first will also accelerate your learning (opposed to passing your task to others).

Comment: I went ahead and added a piece of code at the end that should resemble what I had in mind when I said "As many threads as files". I understand this is not a good solution, but I am not experienced enough to know how to properly separate tasks between fewer threads.

Comment: Regarding this answer:

"as many threads as there are files" would be a rather ineffective method if there are many files. You can communicate with the threads using mutexes and condition variables. You could create a queue where you store the data for the threads to work with and then the threads can pick tasks from that queue until the queue is depleated, then the threads can all exit

Could you please share some code, so I can understand it better please?

Comment: You are supposed to write it.  Google 'C pthreads producer consumer queue'.

Comment: @WeatherVane, the fact that there's a struct with `float` members is not, in and of itself, a red flag. The real red flag would be if you saw code that _calculated_ using float values. The first among the "very specific reasons" that you mentioned is "to reduce the size of data." That struct contains data from a file. It could make sense for the file to contain numbers in binary IEEE single-float form (especially if it contained many of them), and it then would make sense to "parse" the file by simply casting the bytes to `float` fields in a struct.